# Nesting HtmlTemplates in Google Apps Scripts

Tags: xml, templates, google-apps-script

I am trying to create an XML document using Google Apps Script, and the most efficient way to do what I need is to nest one template inside of another.  Is it possible to call `HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile()` and `evaluate()` from inside of another template?

My attempt did not work, so I'm wondering if it's feasible.

**Update**:

```
<?
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
     Logger.log(i + ' testResults ' + data[i])
     var p = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('rvaProductTemplate');
     p.data = data[i] 
     ?>
     <?!= p.evaluate().getContent() ?>
     <?
  } 
?>
```

It worked perfectly, but I was wondering if it's necessary to close the scriptlet, open the force-print scriptlet, and then reopen the scriptlet.  Is there a nicer way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's entirely possible.

```
HtmlService.createTemplate("Look ma, nested templates:" + 
    "<?!= HtmlService.createTemplate('it works!').evaluate().getContent() ?>")
```

Post a snippet that isn't working for you.

Comment: Sorry, it's long gone.  But it definitely didn't match yours.  Where does the `<?!= ... ?>` syntax come from?  I can't find it documented.

Comment: See 'Force-Printing Scriptlets' under https://developers.google.com/apps-script/html_service#HowTemplatesWork

Comment: I was forced (pun intended) to close the scriptlet, open the force-printing scriptlet, then reopen the scriptlet.  It's awkward, so I was wondering if there is a better way.
See update above for code snippet.

Comment: You can always do out.append() instead of closing and opening the scriptlet. The 'out' variable is implicit in templates. All of this is in that same linked documentation.

Comment: That should be 'output', not 'out'.